# Laravel Form Facade For Select with extra Tag on one option

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a select with this option in html form select.

```
 <select name="position" id="position" class='position metadata form-control' data-parsley-required data-parsley-required-message="Please select the one position">
             <option value="">Select Position</option>
            {{ $options = App\Metadata::all()->where('category','position') }}
             @foreach($options as $option)
                <option value="{{$option->item}}">{{$option->item}}</option>
                @endforeach
            <option value="1" mytag='position'>Define New</option>
        </select>
```

The Form Facade for this work like this

```
$options = App\Metadata::where('category', 'department')->orderBy('item')->pluck('item', 'item');
   $options->prepend('Define New', '1');
   $options->prepend('Select department', '0');
    ?>                                                                                              
{!! Form::select('department', $options , null, ['class' => 'department metadata form-control', 'id'=>'department']) !!}
```

The problem is how do I add **mytag**  $options->prepend('Define New', '1');  to the last option on the select in the form facade

Comment: Using models in your views is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Adding additional elements to Laravel's collection:

You should do this in your controller:

```
$metaDataOptions = App\MetaData::orderBy('item')->pluck('item');

//This will be the first option
$metaDataOptions->prepend('Select department', '0');

//This will be the last option 
$metaDataOptions->push('Define New', '1');
```

then return your view with `$metaDataOptions`:

`return view('insert_your_view')->withOptions($metaDataOptions);`

And in your view pass `$options` to `Form::select()`:

```
{!! Form::select('department', $options , null, ['class' => 'department metadata form-control', 'id'=>'department']) !!}
```

---

#### Adding custom attributes to option:

You need to define your own `"type"` of element to `Form`. This can be achieved by using `Form::macro`: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#custom-macros

Comment: It works. Wanted to add extra tag to the last option.  Like <option value="1"  * mytag ='department' *>Define New</option>

Comment: sorry extra attribute to the options <option value ="1"  mytag="department">Define New</option>. Want to add mytag attribute to the last option

Answer (score 0):

Use `push()` instead of preprend.

> **push()**
>
> The push method appends an item to the end of the collection.

Your code:

```
$options = App\Metadata::where('category', 'department')->orderBy('item')->pluck('item', 'item');
   $options->push('Define New', '1');
   $options->push('Select department', '0');
    ?>                                                                                              
{!! Form::select('department', $options , null, ['class' => 'department metadata form-control', 'id'=>'department']) !!}
```

As extra defining variables, making queries, call a model or applying complicated logic on the view is a very bad practice and should be done on the Controller itself.